# If $F_n=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^{2^n} [a_{in},b_{in}]$, $F_n\subseteq F_{n-1}$, and $F=\bigcap_{n} F_n$, then $F$ has m.z. iff $\lim_{n\to\infty} |F_n|=0$

Tags: real-analysis

We work with this definition.

> Let $F\subseteq [0,1]$ be a set. Then we say that $F$ has measure zero iff for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a sequence $\{J_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of open intervals such that $J_n\subseteq [0,1]$, $$F\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} J_n$$ and $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|J_n|<\varepsilon.$$

I want to prove this:

Let $F\subseteq [0,1]$ be a closed set which is given by 
$$F=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} F_n$$
where each $F_n$ is closed and satisfies (For every $n$) $F_n\supseteq F_{n+1}$ and
$$F_n=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^{2^n} I_{i,n}$$
where, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $I_{i,n}$ are disjoint closed intervals.

Then $F$ has measure zero in the above sense iff the sequence given by
$$s_n=\sum_{i=1}^{2^n}|I_{i,n}|$$
converges to $0$.

---

I have already proved that if $s_n\to 0$ then $F$ has measure zero in the above sense. I want to prove the converse, but I haven't been able.

To prove the converse, if necessary, we can also assume that the length of the intervals $I_{i,n}$ is the same for all $i$, in a way the sequence becomes
$$s_n=2^n|I_{1,n}|.$$

I tried to prove that for every open cover $C$ (Made of intervals) of $F$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $F_n\subseteq \bigcup_{I\in C} I$, but I don't even know if that's true.

---

I know this is a weak version of a theorem for measures, but I want to prove it without using measure theory and Lebesgue measure (If we can rephrase some facts of measure theory in a way that they don't rely on measure theory, it's OK to use them).

---

So, in short, I want to prove the converse, without using measure theory. Is there any way I could do that?

And... if we supposed that we were able to prove that $|I_{i,n}|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, would we be able to use that fact to prove the result?